# divs showing correct for around 0.3 seconds

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm working on css for a site for school.
What i want is a few divs

```
---------------------------------



top div, almost 50 % of screen



---------------------------------
small div that has a background color
---------------------------------



bottom div, almost 50 % of screen



---------------------------------
```

Here is what i have at the moment:
http://doekewartena.nl/scriptie_reader_01/reader_test.php

When i load the page everything looks good for like 0.3 seconds and then it's gone.
If i hover over the dom elements in chrome then they show up at the correct positions with the correct sizes but i can't see them.

Can someone see what's going on?

Comment: What are you using the JS scripts for?

Comment: `-1` Read This: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: thx sourabh, i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're positioning your text image with `position: fixed`, which will move it on top of all other statically positioned elements. So as soon as the image is loaded (probably after ~0.3s), it overlays everything else on your page.

Comment: thanks, i would have never thought of that.